# Angular language service not working in vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

The Angular language service does not work in VSCode. In HTML there is no intellisense when using <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to component.

The `tsconfig.json` gives no errors when opened in VSCode.

Answer (score 31):

**Reason**:
Angular Language service may not work because of Experimental ivy gets Enables

[image]

**Solution** : we need to disable that or uncheck the box  by going into extension settings.

[image]

Comment: Great works like charm. I even disabled the prompting. Now I realized experimental features can be dangerous try on your own risk.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz after disabling, u need to reload the vs code.

Comment: The fact that this solved my issue - two years later - makes me incredibly sad.

Answer (score 22):

For all other google'ers that end up here the upcoming days: There is a bug in version v0.1100.3 and downgrading to version v0.1100.2 is the solution for many:

https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1063

You can install another version directly in VSCode:

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh, works like a charm! I wasted 2h x.x Thanks!!

Comment: This was the solution for my problem.

Comment: Funny, we are way past this version, every time I get a notification of an upvote I know the latest version is still broken :)

Comment: The same bug has been introduced again in version 14.2.0. For me, 14.1.0 works fine. So, downgraded to 14.1.0.

Answer (score 20):

I use Angular Language Service version 12.2.0. The solution that worked for me is to enable legacy view engine language service.

[image]

****Update****

Now, I am using Angular Language Service version 13.0. It showed errors when I updated Angular to version 13.0, but, when I deselected the use legacy view engine option, the errors are gone.

Answer (score 14):

You can try to restart `Angular Language Service`.

Press `STRG`+`SHITFT`+`P` for opening the Command Palette. Search for `Angular: Restart Angular Language Service`
[image: Screenshot how to Restart Angular Language Service]
Here you can find the [feature request](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/267) and the [pull request](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/pull/392) on github.

Comment: For recent Angular version (above 13), that's probably the right answer!

Answer (score 6):

The problem was a trailing comma in the tsconfig.json. Which is allowed in vscode. but can't parsed as json. 
With `Help` - `Toggle Developer Tools` it shows the message in a browser console.

The problem was solved after removing the trailing comma and restart vsCode / project

[image: see message in developtool bar]

Comment: i had the same problem, removing the invalid trailing comma solved it!

Comment: This answer still works 3 years later. Can't believe it was this!

Answer (score 4):

From [This Medium Article: Angular Language Service is not Working?](https://medium.com/@gparlakov/downgrade-vs-code-extension-d8c2b0440fbe)

1. You need to make sure VS Code does not auto — update the extension version as it does, so we put **“extensions.autoUpdate”: false** in your user settings (works in user level settings only — not available on project level settings ).

To edit your **settings** in **settings.json** , start by **opening** the Command Palette with CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P . From the Command Palette, you have a choice between two commands that edit your **settings**: The **Open Settings (JSON)** command will let you directly edit the **settings JSON file**.

2. Then right click on the extensions and select *Install another version*:

[image: Image show how to click on VScode extension to install another version]

Answer (score 3):

In may case, this was due to a conflict with another extension. I uninstalled some of the extensions (specifically nunjucks) and restarted VSCode, then intellisense on HTML came back.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1753:

> Based on the few comments here for project version, the issue is limited to older projects. We make a best effort to be backwards compatible, but this is not always possible. For older projects, I have pinpointed the breakage to the commit which updated the TypeScript version. This necessary for the extension to work with 14.2. Older projects should install a previous version of the language service that has a bundled TypeScript version compatible with the project. Again, backwards compatibility is a goal but not always possible. The extension version always aims to be compatible with the corresponding version of Angular (14.2 compatible with 14.2, 11 compatible with 11). You can always go back and install the matching extension version for your project (or a newer version with more features, provided it's still compatible). Closing as working as expected.

TL;DR - the solution will depend on the version of your Angular project. You will need to find the latest version of Angular Language Service that works with your project. In my case, I am on Angular `v10.1.0`, and the latest version that worked for me was `v11.2.14`. I went down by major versions.

Keep going back versions via `Uninstall > Install Another Version...` on the extension page until you find the version that works for you.

Comment: Same here, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to disable Experimental-ivy in Angular Language Service extention->settings:

[image: disable experimental-ivy]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular `12.2.5` and Angular Language Service `12.2.0`. Nothing from above worked in my case, so what I tried as a last resort was to just:

1. uninstall it
2. restart VS Code
3. then re-install it

And that did the trick! Now intellisense is properly working again in html files.

Answer (score 0):

For me (working on an old Angular project), it was because the template was imported like this:

```
import * as template from './<compontent-name>.component.html';

@Component({
    template: template as any,
...
```

I fixed it by removing the import and use `templateUrl` instead of `template`:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './<compontent-name>.component.html',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (in 2023) what worked was deleting the **Angular language service**, then restarting the vscode, then installing the extension again. Its important that when the vscode ask if you want to install all the recommended extensions you answer **install**.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled visual code and then installed it and it was solved (I have a mac by the way)

Answer (score -1):

try it , may be solved

VSCode - User Settings

"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",

to

"editor.snippetSuggestions": "inline",